# Can I detect a cycle in an undirected graph without a parent map?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I am trying to detect whether an undirected graph contains cycles or not. This is my pseudo-code:

```
BFSVisit(node, visited){ // Visiting all nodes in the graph that can be reached from "node"
    containsCycle ← false
    visited.add(node)
    queue ← empty queue
    queue.add(node)
    while (queue is not empty){
        thisNode ← queue.pop()
        for (neighbor in thisNode.edges){
            if (neighbor is in visited and neighbor != thisNode){
                containsCycle ← true
            }
            if (neighbor is not in visited){
                visited.add(neighbor)
                queue.add(neighbor)
            }
        }
    }
    return containsCycle
}
```

However, chatgpt tells me that my code is wrong, specifically the first if-test, where I intend to check for cycles. I thought that I could detect a cycle by checking if a node that is not the parent node of the current node, has been visited. If this condition is true, then we have a cycle. And how I see it, thisNode is the parent node of each node in the for-loop.

I have seen other solutions where people use a parent map, and I could do that, but I wanted to see if there was another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to implement your algorithm in any language and test it out. In case you find a problem with your code, post a question regarding it. Mentioning ChatGPT as your "proofreader" is already a bad sign, but having a look at your pseudocode also reveals several errors that you could detect yourself with a simple run. Implement it, test it, debug it and the ask the questions you find relevant. You will find that much more productive and make more people want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm isn't correct. It doesn't implement what you describe when you say:

> I thought that I could detect a cycle by checking if a node that is not the parent node of the current node, has been visited

I guess you thought you had implemented the "not the parent" rule by doing this check: `neighbor != thisNode`, but that merely checks whether the edge is a self-reference. We should check here that `neighbor != parentOf(thisNode)`.

Imagine the following graph:

```
        1
       /
      2
```

It is clear this graph has no cycles, yet when we start the function at node 1, we get this:

- First the queue has 1, and this node is marked as visited.
- In the first iteration of the loop, node 1 is popped from the queue
- The first (and only) neighbor is 2, and it is not yet visited, so it is marked as visited and added to the queue. The queue now has one entry.
- In the second iteration of the loop, node 2 is popped from the queue
- The first (and only) neighbor is 1 (and it is not `thisNode` which is 2), and it has been visited, so the function concludes there is a cycle, which is clearly wrong.

As you stated yourself, the "parent" of the current node should be excluded from the neighbors list. That is why some algorithms use a parent map. Another way to achieve that is to push (node, parent) pairs on the queue. Or you could extend the `visited` set to a map, so it serves both the "visited" and the "parent" feature. Here is the adapted pseudocode that implements the first idea:

```cpp
BFSVisit(node, visited){
    containsCycle ← false
    visited.add(node)
    queue ← empty queue
    queue.add((node, null))  // The parent of the first node is null (i.e. no parent)
    while (queue is not empty){
        (thisNode, parent) ← queue.pop()
        for (neighbor in thisNode.edges){
            if (neighbor is in visited and neighbor != parent){  // compare with parent
                containsCycle ← true
                break // No need to continue
            }
            if (neighbor is not in visited){
                visited.add(neighbor)
                queue.add((neighbor, thisNode)) // thisNode is the parent of neighbor
            }
        }
    }
    return containsCycle
}
```